# How can I get true, if a number is in all the columns of a matrix?

Tags: java, matrix

My question is simple, I just want to return true if my number is in all the columns of a matrix, for example 3x3.

```
public class matrixcolumns {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int [][] matrix = {{3,2,4},{5,2,6},{7,8,2}};
    int num = 2;
    /*Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Introduce a number: ");
    num = sc.nextInt();*/
    System.out.println("The result is: "+checkcolumns(matrix, num));
}

public static boolean checkcolumns(int matrix[][], int num){
    int cont = 0;
    for (int x = 0; x < matrix.length; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < matrix[x].length; y++) {
            if (num == matrix[x][y]){
                cont++;
            }
        }
    }
    if (cont == 3){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: To be a tad nitpicky, you haven't actually asked a question here. Plus, here's my question: how do you think you could do that? Show us your efforts please.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils I'm trying something like this, but I dont know how to continue now.

Comment: You make nothing in the `if` block...so your loops computes nothing

Comment: What if you have this matrix: `{{1, 2, 3}, {2, 2, 2}, {0, 0, 2}}` What would be the result then? It has 5 number `2` in total, should it return `false`? or `true`? It has 1 number `2` in each column in second row

Comment: Could you please be more specific? Your question isnt very clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before anything, follow [Java naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html):

- `firstWordLowerCaseVariable`
- `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`
- `FirstWordUpperCaseClass`
- `ALL_WORDS_UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`

And use them consistently, this will make your code easier to read for you and us.

Next, your `if` statement does nothing, I think it's because you don't know what to do with it.

Well, if you add `count++` it *could* work, but what if you have more than 1 number `2` per column? Then your algorithm won't work

So, for this case, you need to fix your algorithm, I made that actually in the following code:

```
public class MatrixColumns {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] matrix = {
            {1, 2, 3}, 
            {2, 0, 0}, 
            {0, 0, 2}
        };

        int[][] secondMatrix = {
            {1, 2, 3}, 
            {2, 2, 2}, 
            {0, 0, 0}
        };

        int[][] thirdMatrix = {
            {2, 2, 2}, 
            {2, 2, 2}, 
            {2, 2, 2}
        };

        int num = 2;
        System.out.println("The result is: " + checkColumns(matrix, num, false));
        System.out.println("The result is: " + checkColumns(secondMatrix, num, false));
        System.out.println("The result is: " + checkColumns(thirdMatrix, num, false));

        System.out.println("The result is: " + checkColumns(matrix, num, true));
        System.out.println("The result is: " + checkColumns(secondMatrix, num, true));
        System.out.println("The result is: " + checkColumns(thirdMatrix, num, true));
    }

    //This method returns the column in which the number was found and -1 if it wasn't found in any column
    private static int checkRow(int[] row, int num, int startFrom) {
        for (int i = startFrom == -1 ? 0 : startFrom; i < row.length; i++) {
            if (row[i] == num) {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }

    //If there can be more than 1 number 2 in each column, we set "allowRepeatInRow" to true and it will look for all the column values, otherwise set it to false
    public static boolean checkColumns(int matrix[][], int num, boolean allowRepeatInRow) {
        boolean[] results = new boolean[matrix.length]; //Array where we will store the results of each column

        int column = 0;
        int nextColumn = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
            if (allowRepeatInRow) {
                do {
                    column = checkRow(matrix[i], num, nextColumn);
                    if (column != -1) {
                        results[column] = true; //We change the value to "true" on the column where the number was found for each row.
                    }
                    nextColumn = column + 1;
                } while (column < matrix.length - 1 && column != -1);
            } else {
                column = checkRow(matrix[i], num, 0);
                if (column != -1) {
                    results[column] = true; //We change the value to "true" on the column where the number was found for each row.
                }
            }
        }

        //We iterate over the results array, if any of them is "false" we return false as there is at least one column where the number was not found   
        for (int i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            if (!results[i]) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true; //We return true if the above method didn't found any false column, and thus all columns have at least one number "2"
    }
}
```

The results from the above program are as follows:

```
The result is: true
The result is: false
The result is: false
The result is: true
The result is: true
The result is: true
```

Why does it produce 2 different results for the `second` and `third` matrix? and not for the first one?

- The first matrix has a single `2` in every column
- The second matrix has 1 `2` in first row and 3 `2` in second one, then it returns the index of the first `2` found. If you don't keep looking for the rest of the columns, it just skips the rest of them.
- The third matrix is the same for the second one, if you only return the first one, it will skip the columns 2 and 3.

Hope this helps.

Comment: You're welcome, just for your future questions be sure to think of some edge cases as I did above and to follow Java naming conventions as I recommended above :)

Comment: And yeah, I didn't use the if because I was trying to use the if with the cont, but obviously if I had more than a 2 it won't work .So thank you again.

Comment: The trick here is the `results` boolean array which gets filled with the index of each `2` found :) Good luck

Answer (score 0):

If you find your number you increase cont by one and break the inner for loop.